# Azure Worker Role Assembly Location

Tags: azure

Using Windows Azure, I am deploying two worker roles and I have questions about the DLL files:

1. Using the Azure Storage Emulator, do the worker roles pull assemblies from the GAC or do they pull assemblies from the bin folder?
2. How would I know that assemblies are missing or assemblies have an incorrect version? What is the recommended way to log errors in the worker roles and where can I find this log? I have code that works fine on my local machine, but it seems to throw errors on Windows Azure. I have some code doing database logging, but I see no error.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't use GAC. It uses whatever assemblies it references. Make sure they all say copy local.